# CakePhP, Jquery Mobile, Ipad - Adding Record Twice

Tags: ipad, cakephp, jquery-mobile

Using CakePhp with Jquery Mobile on an ipad,

The problem is sometimes when adding records on the ipad it add the record twice,
as if the save button has been pressed twice by accident.

Both records get different IDs but the data is the same.

How can I stop the save button accepting multiple presses.

Currently using

```
<button type="submit" data-theme="b" data-inline="true">Save</button>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before saving the data verify if it is a post request or not. If you are not verifying the post method after saving the data when refreshing the page it will save once again.

You can do like this in the controller

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->ModelName->create();
    if ($this->ModelName->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Model has been saved'));
    }
}
```